# Processmaker 4.6 community docker-executor-php not working

Tags: laravel, docker, curl, composer-php, processmaker

I'm having an issue with ProcessMaker 4.6 community edition running on a debian machine.

I was triying to install a script language (php) and apparently the script to install relies on a docker container to do this job.

I'm a newbie on the docker stuff, but I understand that when I run my php artisan docker-excecutor-php:install command, when it gets to the point of installing composer, it fails with a error (6) timeout.

Apparently my docker image does not have access to the internet to download composer.

Anyone had this issue before?

thanks.

I've tried to modify the DockerFile for the php executor adding the --network='host' to try to bridge my container network to my host network.

Comment: Please share more details. Is this a Laravel issue, a Docker issue, a Composer issue, or a cURL issue?

Comment: i'm not sure, but I think is a Docker container issue. Maybe something with closed ports? Because I get this answer     '

Step 4/13 : RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
 ---> Running in 6e1655fb12d8
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: getcomposer.org
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php' returned a non-zero code: 6

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. It looks like you're facing network problems. Composer itself cannot resolve them

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I installed Processmaker from bitnami on aws. Everything was smooth until I tried to install the php executor from within the processmaker gui. Nothing showed up. I then tried doing it from cli, but it seems that the executor was already messed up. I had to start a new instance and installed it only from cli and it worked. I followed bitnami's  documentation found here [bitnami processmaker](https://bitnami.com/stack/processmaker)

Comment: I will try what You did

Comment: I did what you suggested and it worked somehow. Now the php script executor is installed, but it does not execute.

Comment: I finally use the docker approach to install ProcessMaker (not without hassle) and I have it working properly.

Comment: I haven't reached a point where I need to run custom code, so maybe it won't work either. Thanks for your comment